# Oracle APEX 21.2 - Shuttle Render Issue when Read Only

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a shuttle that works/displays fine in default situations. The CSS/Layout rendering when the Shuttle is Read-Only is broken. The Shuttle is a Page Item inside a Static Region on a Modal page (Drawer). Has anyone else come across this?

Default Rendering:

[image]

Read-Only Rendering:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you modify "Dialog Template" property and don't use "Drawer"? To me (at least, when I tested it), this looks *suspicious*.

Comment: As a workaround, you could have a different page item that displays the selected values. Instead of shuttle item read only, hide it and show this alternative page item.

Comment: I found issue. Someone had applied css formatting to display items in a static application.css file that adjusted margins. Didn't think to look there first. Thanks to you both for helping me pinpoint the issue.